# Regular expression validation to prevent spam registrations?

Tags: php, regex, html, validation

I added an input field to my registration form that validate the value by regex to avoid spam automated registrations. I don't know if it will work or the spam bots will by pass it.

Here is my code:

```
        <label>Type "Word" in the field*</label>
        <input  pattern="(Word|word)" type="text" name="antispamfield"
        id="antispamfield" required/>
```

The user now will have to enter "word" in order to complete registration. But, does the spam will pass the validation? Does anyone have a better idea rather than using regex or javascript?

Comment: given that you've provided the answer to the question right in the input tag itself, it's not going to be much of a restriction...

Comment: Yes, but this is in case my website is specifically targeted. Right? @MarcB

Comment: You need to use a proper CAPTCHA, such as the Google reCaptcha to be relatively free from spam.  Requires a bit of code on your end though.  Your method will probably prevent some spam getting through.

Comment: Maybe you could create an email with a registration link which a user must click to activate his account like some big companys do. Their should be away to by pass this too (maybe by scan such an email and click containing link).

Comment: @HaukurHaf I don't want to use a captcha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a spammer pass the validation?

Yes. Easily.

If the browser can read the "secret word" (and obviously it can), then a spammer can read it: it is plainly there in his `curl` (or equivalent) output.

He can therefore tweak his script to read the word in the `<label>Type "Word"</label>` field and automatically enter it in your `antispamfield` text input field.

**Other ideas**

There are many approaches to fend off form spammers. None of them are perfect. Some of them are:

1. A token saved in the session before submitting. If you get a submission without the right token, it's more than suspicious.
2. Controlling the number of comments per IP address per time period.
3. Requiring the user to be logged it before he or she can comment.
4. A captcha, such as ReCaptcha
5. `Are you Human?` challenges

Some of these require a database.

Comment: Thank you for these information, do you have a link that explains how to generate a token for this purpose?

Comment: @MinaIsaac From memory, I think Chris Schiffert covers it in his PHP security book. Basically, you place the token on the form as a hidden input field and later check it in the POST data, and compare with the one stored in the session. As for the formula to generate a token... It doesn't matter very much, even a random int would do, because if the guy keeps trying, your flood prevention will catch it. That being said if you search "generate unique token for form" you might get some other ideas. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CAPTCHA (http://www.captcha.net/) in your validation. I think that is much more robust than yours. Also, just a note: you may want to include "WORD" in your pattern as some people enter all caps to such validation.

Comment: Good point, I should add WORD too, Thanks for that. I don't want to use any captcha

Answer (score -1):

I would use some text question, which is hard to guess by most of the robots like "Who was the second US president?" and check the answer by server script when form sent.